# restore from entry disk image with dd, to unallocated space or specific partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have already created an image with `dd` for the entry disk 
the image for windows 10, and I restore it from Ubuntu recovery mode

When I want to restore the windows I erase hdd and remove all partitions

```
wget -O- 'http://your_webhosting.com/Windows10template.img.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda
```

Image size is 5GB compressed (gz format), 20 GB uncompressed

I had three partitions

```
 Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
    /dev/sda1  *         2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda2         1026048  208089944  207063897  98.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3       208089949 1953520064 1745430116 832.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
    /dev/sda5       208090012 1953520064 1745430053 832.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

All I needed was to restore the image which created from entry disk
to sda1 and sda2 only, and keep sda5 (my own files)

I removed sda1 and sda2, and created a new partition sda1 100GB
and restored the image with

```
wget -O- 'http://your_webhosting.com/Windows10template.img.gz' | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda1
```

but nothing changed. My partitions are now like this

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  195311615  195309568  93,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       208089949 1953520064 1745430116 832,3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       208090012 1953520064 1745430053 832,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The normal and working method erased the hdd completely.
I need a working method to restore it to one partition only or unallocated space

```
/dev/sda1
```

How to do this with `dd`?

**UPDATE**

```
$ fdisk -l Windows10template.img
Disk Windows10template.img: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x266de740

Device                 Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
Windows10template.img1 *       2048  1026047  1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Windows10template.img2      1026048 41940991 40914944 19,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. How (or, more precisely, of what) did you create the drive image? If it contains multiple partitions, what's the partition layout inside the image (use `fdisk -l Windows10template.img`)? In any case it would be best if you downloaded the drive image to a local file so you can 1) inspect it and 2) restore parts of it more easily.

Comment: edit the first post

Comment: the problem is image is large 20GB, I can't download it in local rescue mode (only give me 8GB and my rams). I need to restore from the img directly to the sda1 (should after restore its repartition sda1 to sda1 and sda2)

Comment: You can use regular storage in rescue mode via `mount`. It's possible to do all of this on streams (e. g. on the output of `zcat`) but it's going to much harder and involve manual offset and length calculations and typing which, when done incorrectly, may result in the loss of any or all current data on the drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the partition boundaries on the drive backup image line up with a subset of those of the current disk layout it would be relatively simple to cut out the relevant part out of the `gunzip` output and write it to the right parts of `/dev/sda` with `dd`, but I'm not going to write an answer that is going to help only you yet overwrite anybody else's data. Even for yourself there's a large risk to make a wrong offset calculation or to type in a wrong number to the same result.

Instead it would be much better to decompress the drive image onto a large enough storage medium and operate on that. You can do that even in recovery mode. But it would be much easier if you did this with a graphical user interface (e. g. from a live DVD/USB) – even if you end up doing most of this on a terminal.

I assume that there are at least 25 GB (enough to hold the compressed and the decompressed backup image) free on the file system on `/dev/sda5`.

1. Mount the file system on `/dev/sda5`.

   - You can use the file manager or *Gnome Disks* to mount the file system.
   - Alternatively on the command line:

     ```
     udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda5 --options rw
     ```

     `udisksctl` will tell you where the drive was mounted.

   I'll assume that the mountpoint is located at `/media/ubuntu/my-data`. Adjust the following commands according to the actual mountpoint.
2. Download the compressed drive image onto the previously mounted file system

   - using a web browser or
   - your favourite HTTP client,
   - e. g. on the command line:

     ```
     wget -P /media/ubuntu/my-data 'http://your_webhosting.com/Windows10template.img.gz'
     ```
3. Decompress the image and store the output on the same file system.

   - You can use an archive manager like *File-Roller* (which your file manager should open automatically as the default action on a `.gz` file) or
   - a command line tool, e. g.:

     ```
     gunzip /media/ubuntu/my-data/Windows10template.img.gz
     ```
4. Set up a loop device for the decompressed drive image.

   - You should be able to tell your favourite graphical file manager to mount the image file (via its context menu) and to figure out the device path through the properties dialogue of the newly created loop device (accessible via its context menu).
   - Alternatively on the command line:

     ```
     udisksctl loop-setup --file /media/ubuntu/my-data/Windows10template.img --read-only
     ```

     `udisksctl` will show you the path to the loop device.

   I'll assume that the loop device path is `/dev/loopX`. Adjust the following commands according to the actual device path.
5. Normally, in both cases, `udisksctl` will tell the kernel to detect the partition table inside the loop device (backed by the drive image) and to add additional block device nodes for the detected partitions, i. e. `/dev/loopXp1` and `/dev/loopXp2`.

   If it didn't:

   ```
   sudo partprobe /dev/loopX
   ```
6. Copy the previously exposed partitions *individually* to the target device.

   - You can use a graphical partition manager like *Gnome Disks* or *GParted* (which are the safer route since the nature of the target device is more obvious with some contextual graphical info which makes accidental selection and subsequent data loss less likely; they outright forbid alteration of partitions in use).
   - Alternatively on the command-line:

     ```
     sudo dd if=/dev/loopXp1 of=/dev/sdX1 bs=8M
     sudo dd if=/dev/loopXp2 of=/dev/sdX2 bs=8M
     ```

     Replace `loopX` and `sdX`<sup>1</sup> with the appropriate device names. **Double-check that you typed in the correct target device path and that the `/dev/sdX` is actually what you think it is! Don't rely on the kernel to reassign the same name to a block device across system reboots!**

     You can verify the identity of `/dev/sdX` by looking at its partition layout (e. g. with `fdisk /dev/sdX` or Gnome Disks) or use the unique and (mostly) stable device identifiers in `/dev/disk/by-*`.
7. Verify that `/dev/sdX1` and `/dev/sdX2` contain the intended data.
8. You're done. Reboot into Windows or do whatever.
9. Optional clean-up:

   1. If you want to delete the drive image *before* the reboot in the previous step, remove the loop device first before you are allowed to do so.

      - You can use the file manager again or *Gnome Disks*, both of which should offer an *eject* button associated with the loop device.
      - Alternatively on the command-line:

        ```
        udisksctl loop-delete --block-device /dev/loop7
        ```
   2. Delete the leftover drive image whenever and as you like.

---

<sup>1</sup> `sdX` is a placeholder that does not exist in any sane default *nix setup to avoid data loss by people who copy and paste the verbatim command into their terminal by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

**dd** is a very powerful but also very dangerous tool. Please **backup** whatever is new on the target drive (for example in partition /dev/sda5) before you start tampering with dd.

I think the least dangerous method would be to

1. clone 'everything' from the backup image to an extra drive
2. clone the first partition from the extra drive to the first partition of the target drive.
3. But you have damaged the head of the drive (the first mibibyte), so you need to clone that part from the backup image to the target drive too. You can use `count=N` to copy only N blocks and the default block size is 512 bytes.

Another faster, but more risky method would be to clone the first part of the backup, from the head end until the end of the first partition.

Comment: sorry I don't now how to do this, I have edit the first post to show what img include, I want img1 as sda1 and img2 as sda2 . how to retore it with this way

Comment: Would it be possible for you to buy or borrow an external drive with at least 20 GiB, for example a USB 3 pendrive with 32 GB? It would make the process safer and easier compared to doing it directly from the compressed image 'soaring in the cloud'.